# How to call a variable from a keylistener to a different class

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a payroll system and I'm having trouble using the variable in and action listener to my condition, somehow it cant see the variable I've declared in actionlistener, I've tried using calling it in a class but wasn't sure what I did wrong cause it didn't work. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

```
   import java.io.File; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import
    java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List; import
    java.util.Scanner; import javax.swing.*; import java.awt.*; import
    java.awt.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
 public class kapoy extends JFrame{

    public static JTextField text1;
    public static JTextField text2;
    public JLabel label1;
    public JLabel label2; 
    public JPanel panel1;
    public JPanel panel2; 
    public JPanel panel3; 
    public JPanel panel4;
     public kapoy()      {
        text1 = new JTextField();
        text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
        text2 = new JTextField();
        text2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
        label1 = new
        JLabel("Inpute Employee ID: "); 
        label2 = new JLabel("Input workedDays: "); 
        panel1 = new JPanel();  
        panel1.setLocation(0,0);
        panel1.setSize(300,40);  
        panel1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel1.add(label1); 
        panel1.add(text1);  
        add(panel1);
        panel2 = new JPanel();   
        panel2.setLocation(0,40);    
        panel2.setSize(300,40);      
        panel2.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.add(label2);        
        panel2.add(text2);      
        add(panel2);
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLocation(0,80); 
        panel3.setSize(400,200);
        panel3.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(panel3);
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel4.setLocation(300,0);
        panel4.setSize(100,80);
        panel4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        add(panel4);
        setSize(410,300);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Pay Roll by Migz");    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        kapoy cn = new kapoy();         cn.setVisible(true);

                    text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                public void  keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {
                     try {
            /**Cant use this-->**/int x = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                            text1.setText("");
                        }
                }           });

        try {
            File f = new File("D:/Users/DAVID Family/Desktop/Employees.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            List<Employee> people = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split(" ");
                int Id = Integer.parseInt(details[0]);
                String name = details[1];
                int rate = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                Employee p = new Employee(Id, name, rate);

            /**in here-->**/if (x == Id){
                people.add(p);
                }
            }

           for(Employee p: people){
                System.out.println(p.toString());
           }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}


class Employee{

    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private int rate;

    public Employee(int Id, String name, int rate){
        this.Id = Id;
        this.setName(name);
        this.rate = rate;
    }







    public int getId() {
    return Id; }

public void setId(int Id)
{
    this.Id = Id; }

/public void setName(String
name) {
    this.name = name; }

public String getName() {
    return name; }

public int getrate() {
    return rate; }

public void setrate(int rate) {
    this.rate = rate; }

public String toString(){
    return this.Id + " " + this.name + " " + this.rate; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you have defined `int x = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());` is the **local** variable of method `keyReleased` as you have defined it inside the method, so the scope of this variable will always be within that method only.

It means you will only be able to use this variable inside method only, not outside it.

If you want to use it in your class, i.e. outside that method, then you should try with some **instance** variable.

[Check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener`s to modify the state of fields, this could cause concurrent modification exceptions, the underlying `Document` could be modified before your `KeyListener` is notified and doesn't take into account what would happen in the user pastes text into your field.

Instead, make use of `DocumentFilter` if you want to restrict what is entered into the field in real time and/or a `DocumentListener` if you want to be notified when changes occur to the field's `Document`

Take a look at [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter), [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) and [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details

You also need to understand that you are operating within in a event driven environment.  This means that user actions can occur at any time and in any order.  The only thing you can do is wait until some event occurs and respond to.

This means that something like...

```
kapoy cn = new kapoy();
cn.setVisible(true);

int x = -1;
text1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        try {
            x = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            text1.setText("");
        }
    }
});

try {
    File f = new File("D:/Users/DAVID Family/Desktop/Employees.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

    List<Employee> people = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        //...
        Employee p = new Employee(Id, name, rate);

        if (x == Id) {
            people.add(p);
        }
    }

    //...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Won't work, because by the time your code reaches `if (x == Id) {` `x` will still be `-1`, as the program won't have been able to respond to any key events...

You may, also, want to take a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)